# Apply Entity Migration Only to Certain Environments

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.1

I have 3 existing environments Development, Staging and Production, each of which has several databases. I want to be able to run a sql script through a migration but have it only affect Staging and Production.

I have created the migration and inserted the SQL script.

```
public partial class TrimPTPrimaryPCCodes : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE public.\"Table\" set \"Code\" = TRIM(\"Code\");");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
```

How can I have this migration only apply if the Environment is "Production"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the value of the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable either using `IHostingEnvironment::IsProduction` method if you have an IHostingEnvironment in your scope or by the static method `System.GetEnvironmentVariable ("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")`

Comment: Thanks `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");` did the trick.